# A Regex matching in space separated strings

Tags: regex

How to write a regex that could satisfy the following requirements?

Match a single "World"

Match: `Hello World`

No Match: `HelloWorld`, `WorldHello`

Currently I'm using `((?i)World)`, but `WorldHello` still got matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use word boundaries,

```
(?i)\bWorld\b
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lR5lT8/5)

**Explanation:**

- `(?i)` Case insensitive match.
- `\b` Word boundary. Matches between a word character and a non word character.
- `world` Matches the Literal string `world`. Note that, because of case-insensitive modifier, it don't care about whether the string is in uppercase or lowercase.
- `\b` Word boundary.

Comment: ooh, a regex wizard! Something O/T slightly, but I tried earlier to do `re.sub(r"\bliteralwordhere\b", "", mytext)` to remove all occurances of my word literal and it failed until I removed the trailing word boundary. Why is that? EDIT: nevermind, I just realized it's because I was looking for a `\b` after a `"`, which is not a word character.

Comment: @AdamSmith get into here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767/regex . I will try to solve your problem.